# TWIG: trim two characters from a string

Tags: php, twig, twig-filter

I'm very new to TWIG.

I have a string `₹1,324`, or `₹324` compare it with integer value 3000, so I want to trim characters `₹` and `,`

I know how to trim one character.

```
{% if foo |trim('₹')  |number_format > 3000 %}
```

help me to how to do it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It feels like this is the sort of comparison that should be done in the controller or method, and the result sent to the view.

Comment: Alternatively you might want to look at [extending Twig](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) to create a custom filter.

Answer (score 2):

Use php `str_replace`

`str_replace([",", "₹"], "", $str);`

replace for twig

`{% if foo |replace({'₹':'', ',':''})  |number_format > 3000 %}`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html

So how you would ideally do it would be pass in just a regular integer to your twig template, do the comparison & then if you need to display the whole string on the page, prefix the `number_format` to get the comma and if you wish decimal places.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, this is not a job for a view. But the [`replace` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) can do this:

```
{% if foo |replace({'₹':'', ',':''}) > 3000 %}
```

You don't want to use the [`number_format` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) as this will just reintroduce punctuation.